# Convert data structure in Python

Tags: python, list, data-structures

The data I have look like this:

`Ａ=[ａ,ｂ,ｃ,...,n］`
`Ｂ=[ｘ,ｙ,ｚ,...,n]`

I would like to convert this data to following:

`Ｃ=[((ａ, ｘ), 1),((ｂ, ｙ), 1),((ｃ, ｚ), 1),...,((n, n), 1)]`

**a,b,c,x,y,z are all integers**

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Are you looking for `zip`?

Comment: what is the `1`? just a constant ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming lengths are equal I would do it following way

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [101,102,103]
C = [((a,b),1) for a,b in zip(A,B)]
print(C)
```

output

```
[((1, 101), 1), ((2, 102), 1), ((3, 103), 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely, the problem has been bothering me for a long time

Answer (score 1):

If the `1` is only a constant :

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

c = [(x,1) for x in zip(a,b)]

c
[((0, 10), 1),
 ((1, 11), 1),
 ((2, 12), 1),
 ((3, 13), 1),
 ((4, 14), 1),
 ((5, 15), 1),
 ((6, 16), 1),
 ((7, 17), 1),
 ((8, 18), 1),
 ((9, 19), 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this and there are other examples here which are correct. I'd like to add one more which uses the `itertools` package (if you find this interesting, I highly recommend reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)).

```py
from itertools import repeat

A = [1,2,3]
B = [101,102,103]
C = list(zip(zip(A, B), repeat(1)))
print(C)
```

The `repeat()` function from the `itertools` package will infinitely repeat the supplied value. Since the `zip()` builtin function will only zip for the shortest length of either utterable, this will repeat `1` for the length of `A` or `B`, whichever is shortest (or if they're the same length).

Output

```
[((1, 101), 1), ((2, 102), 1), ((3, 103), 1)]
```

If you don't need this to be a list, but can rather let it be a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), you can make this code less verbose.

```
C = zip(zip(A, B), repeat(1))
```